# How to plot length of sentences in range based

Tags: python, bar-chart

This is my code but I am getting the below error! 
df['length'] is length of my sentences in my data

What am I doing wrong?

```
data = df['length']
type(data)
fig  = plt.figure()
ax   = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
data0 = []
data1 = []
data2 = []
data3 = []
data4 = []

if  data.any() < 500:
    data0.append(data)
if  data.any() >= 500  &  data.any() < 1000:
    data1.append(data)
if  data.any() >= 1000 &  data.any() < 1500:
    data2.append(data)
if  data.any() >= 1500 &  data.any() < 2000:
    data3.append(data)
if  data.any() >= 2000 &  data.any() < 2500:
    data4.append(data)

langs = ['0-499', '500-999', '1000-1499', '1500-1999', '2000-2500']
ax.bar(langs, data0, color = 'b', width = 0.25)
ax.bar(langs, data1, color = 'g', width = 0.25)
ax.bar(langs, data2, color = 'r', width = 0.25)
ax.bar(langs, data3, color = 'y', width = 0.25)
ax.bar(langs, data4, color = 'o', width = 0.25)
```

**error** : ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Answer (score 1):

You are not calculating the right thing. If I understand correctly, this is what you actually want -

```
data0 = data[data < 500].size
data1 = data[(data >= 1300) & (data<1000)].size
data2 = data[(data >= 1000) & (data<1500)].size
data3 = data[(data >= 1500) & (data<2000)].size
data4 = data[(data >= 2000) & (data<2500)].size
```

You can achieve similar effect with -

```
data.hist(bins=[500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500])
```